# jQuery hover does not work with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have edited my code to extract only the required parts to make this question easier to understand. The whole code is big as it is a copy of an existing system and there would be too much code to read through.

So - in a nutshell, I have a webpage where I use jQuery hover() and [jQueryContextMenu plugin](https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu).

My HTML page used to look like this:

```
<?php
foreach($characters as $character) {
  echo "<div class='player'>";
    echo "<div>". $character->name. "</div>"; //other character attributes
  echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

My hover function looks like this:

```
$('.player').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('hovering');
        alert("Class added");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hovering');
        alert("Class removed")
    }
);
```

This used to work just fine. I am now learning Angular and I decided to change my HTML to be loaded using AngularJS:

```
<div ng-controller="playerController">
  <div class='player' ng-repeat="character in characters">
      <div>{{character.name}}</div> //..and other character attributes
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have a `playerController` that fetches data from my php backend and converts it into a JSON that Angular consumes.

All of this works fine too.I get the player list and my context menu works as well, I can right click and perform actions.

**ONLY** my `hover()` function does not work! If I do a `console.log($('.player').length)` it prints `0`. The context Menu Plugin is also bound to this same class but it works just fine:

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.player',
    trigger: 'right',
    ... other options
```

I read that this could be because I have to `bind` the event since the DOM element is built by Angular. So I tried below two steps also without any luck (I tried `click` event for testing, in order to make it simple:

```
$(document).bind("click",".player",function(){alert("hi")});

$(document).on("click",".player",function(){alert("hi")});
```

I tried variations:

```
$('.player').bind("click",function(){alert("hi")});

$('.player').on("click",function(){alert("hi")});
```

All of these I tried in the `ready()` function of jQuery but did not work. (No alerts were shown).

Finally I wrapped these two statements inside a function named `jQueryInit()` and I tried triggering these two functions from AngularJS like so:

```
playerController:
... //other lines of code
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', jqueryInit);
```

But that didnt work either. So I am here, hoping someone will show me what is going on here, because I am pretty much clueless at the moment...

Comment: @vinayakj yes they are

Comment: Is `console.log($('.player')).length` a typo?

Comment: A small jsFiddle would be helpful

Comment: @DavidL yes it is. Corrected.

Comment: did you put this in a directive? acting upon angular-controlled elements with jquery outside of a directive doesn't work very well.

Comment: @KevinB: I am new to angular, so I was not sure about how to use directives...I thought I would make it working with each small step and then keep refactoring more code into Angular. You think I should try to put this inside a directive?

Comment: Give this a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to move the JQuery code to a directive:

```
directive('customHover', function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.hover(
 function () {
     $(this).addClass('hovering');
     alert("Class added");
 },
 function () {
     $(this).removeClass('hovering');
     alert("Class removed")
 }
 );
    }
}
});
```

And then use it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="playerController">
<div custom-hover ng-repeat="character in characters">
  <div>{{character.name}}</div> //..and other character attributes
</div>
</div>
```

**Update:**
I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuzzfxnp/21/)

Comment: Awesome! that worked!!Thank you, kind sir...you really did put a smile on my face :) Now let me go and read more on directives and links...

Comment: I have a question: Does the `element` variable represent a jquery object? As in, can I run `element.jqueryFunctions()` on it?

Comment: The `element` variable is a JQuery Lite element, meaning it is a lite version of Jquery, it doesn't contain all the JQuery functions

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one more question... In the HTML, in the div I have an attribute like `data-style={{player.style}}`. In the link function do you know how I can get its value? If I alert `element.attr('data-style')` it just prints `{{player.style}}`...Because what i want to do is, on mouseout get this data-style and apply it back to the div...

Comment: You can use `data-style=player.style` without {{}} and the get it with the `scope` instead of the `attr` I updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuzzfxnp/27/)

Comment: I got it working :) But I am worried a bit about Angular now...it just seems too complex... I am wondering if I will hit more roadblocks if I continue down this path...